# MySQL Double Column Query with only one variable

Tags: mysql, variables, double

Here is my question... in my semi-code...
How to make this work...?
I want to select randomly 2 others id of the same table Mytable depending on the same category product of the first product which is determined by the variable $_GET["product_id1"])...
I hope it's clear enough.

```
SELECT 2 RANDOM id as ID,
       category as CategoryFR,
       brand as BrandFR
From MYTABLE
WHERE (category depends on same id category of id = $_GET["product_id1"])";
```

Thank you very much...

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do in words? The SQL makes limited sense.

Comment: I want to select randomly 2 items from mytable selected by a category depending on the variable product_id1 which is also in the same category product.